# How to create JSON data in a loop in Python?

Tags: python, json

I tried creating loops like this but it gave me error

```
for prod in data:
   productId = prod['productId']
```

Error :

```
productId = prod['productId']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

---

```
{'volume': '1', 'productId': 32702747712, 'evaluateScore': '4.9', 'storeUrl': 'https://www.aliexpress.com/store/1393300', 'lotNum': 1, 'discount': '48%', 'validTime': '2018-06-21', 'storeName': 'MORAZORA', 'productUrl': 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/fashion-2017-hot-sale-top-quality-pu-nubuck-leather-ankle-boots-med-heel-round-toe-solid/32702747712.html', 'packageType': 'piece', 'allImageUrls': 'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB10rBClEUIL1JjSZFrq6z3xFXaq/MORAZORA-Fashion-2018-hot-sale-top-quality-flock-ankle-boots-for-women-autumn-winter-high-heel.jpg,https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB129b2e_J_SKJjSZPiq6z3LpXaR/MORAZORA-Fashion-2018-hot-sale-top-quality-flock-ankle-boots-for-women-autumn-winter-high-heel.jpg,https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1gYNClEUIL1JjSZFrq6z3xFXaJ/MORAZORA-Fashion-2018-hot-sale-top-quality-flock-ankle-boots-for-women-autumn-winter-high-heel.jpg,https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1s04klC7PL1JjSZFHq6AciXXa0/MORAZORA-Fashion-2018-hot-sale-top-quality-flock-ankle-boots-for-women-autumn-winter-high-heel.jpg,https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1AcUgdaagSKJjy0Faq6z0dpXa3/MORAZORA-Fashion-2018-hot-sale-top-quality-flock-ankle-boots-for-women-autumn-winter-high-heel.jpg,https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1TYjLbu7EWeJjSZFMq6x00FXa7/MORAZORA-Fashion-2018-hot-sale-top-quality-flock-ankle-boots-for-women-autumn-winter-high-heel.jpg'}
```

How prod is created :

```
data = aliexpress.get_product_details(['productId', 'productUrl', 'discount', 'evaluateScore',
                                      'volume', 'packageType', 'lotNum', 'validTime', 'storeName', 'storeUrl', 'allImageUrls'], productId)
dmp = json.dumps(data)
for prod in dmp:
    print(prod)
    productId = prod['productId']
    productUrl = prod['productUrl']
    discount = prod['discount']
    evaluateScore = prod['evaluateScore']
    volume = prod['volume']
    packageType = prod['packageType']
    lotNum = prod['lotNum']
    validTime = prod['validTime']
    storeName = prod['storeName']
    storeUrl = prod['storeUrl']
    allImageUrls = prod['allImageUrls']
```

Comment: I guess the `data` is a dictionary which makes `prod` to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes from trying to iterate through the keys of the dictionary:

```
for prod in data:
    print(prod)
```

This returns..

```
 'volume'
 'productId'
 'evaluateScore'
 ...etc
```

When you ask for `'volume'['productId']` Python gets confused - strings support integer indexes, but that string `'productId'` means nothing to the interpreter. Solution is either to put that dict in a list or to just access that element directly with `prod['productId']`

Comment: Is this how you turn dict into list ?

    for prod, value in data.items():
        productId = prod['productId']

Comment: `prod = list(prod)` will do that, but I think you're misunderstanding the problem you're having - that' s almost definitely not what you want it to do. Try just accessing `prod['productId']` instead of looping.

Comment: I can access it directly but I need to create a loop so I can add multiple inserts into database.

Comment: It looks like `for prod in dmp:` does that - iterates over a list. If you need to create a new list of dicts, you can do that fairly easily by creating dicts out of parts of each `prod`.